# Create a function with many parameters and apply it over a list in R

Tags: r, function, iteration

I have a list which includes 2 `data.frames` and would like to apply some analysis to each `data.frame`. I performed my analysis to a single `data.frame` and I want to do the same steps over my list. I am a bit confused on how to do that but I found that the easiest way to do it is by creating a `function` and then to use `lapply`. My code for the single `data.frame` is below

```
setwd("mydir")

#import .txt file
d = read.table("vourlionas.txt",
               header = FALSE,
               sep="", 
               col.names=c("x", "y"), 
               fill=FALSE, 
               strip.white=TRUE,
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#remove the 1st row of the .txt file
d2 = d[-1,]

d3 = substr(d2$x, 1, 6)   
d4 = substr(d2$y, 1, 7)

df <- cbind(d3, d4)

df1 <- as.data.frame(df)

b = apply(as.matrix(df1),2,as.character)

#rename the column names of the matrix
colnames(b) [1] = paste("x")

mode(b) = "numeric"

b2 <- as.data.frame(b)

ch <- chull(b2)
coords <- b2[c(ch, ch[1]), ]

sp_poly <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(coords)), ID=1)))

proj4string(sp_poly) <- CRS("+init=epsg:2100")

sp_poly_df <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(sp_poly, data=data.frame(ID=1))

test1 = spTransform(sp_poly_df, "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")

writeOGR(obj=test1, dsn="mydir", layer = "r"
         driver="ESRI Shapefile", overwrite_layer = TRUE)
```

What I want is the above code, from the point *remove the 1st row of the .txt file* to be included in my function and to apply it in each element of my list.
What I have managed to do so far is to insert my elements as a list

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.txt")
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.delim, sep = "")
```

and to write the `lapply` code

```
lapply(myfiles, testfun)
```

The files of the list can be downloaded from here [enter link description here](https://gofile.io/?c=Hojk0J)

Comment: What does your function look like? Or what isn't working? Do all of your files have the same structure?  I would also recommend transitioning away from `sp` and use `sf` instead for spatial operations, and would probably opt for using `purrr` and `map` instead of an `lapply` (personal preference but also easier to read)

Comment: I want to insert all these operations mentioned inside my function. What do you mean by «same structure»? Same number of rows and columns? If so, then no they don't have the same structure. I will check the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but here is how I would approach it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
library(sp)
#Get list of files
mydir="C:/path/to/textfiles/"
temp = list.files(mydir,pattern="*.shp$",full.names = TRUE)
fn = list.files(mydir,pattern="*.txt$")

temp=enframe(temp)%>%
  mutate(savedir=fn)

temp = temp %>%
  #load in your table
  mutate(data = map(value,~read.table(.,header = FALSE,
                                      sep="", 
                                      col.names=c("x", "y"), 
                                      fill=FALSE, 
                                      strip.white=TRUE,
                                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))

#Your function

myfunction = function(d,save_name){

  #remove the 1st row of the .txt file
  d2 = d[-1,]

  d3 = substr(d2$x, 1, 6)   
  d4 = substr(d2$y, 1, 7)

  df <- cbind(d3, d4)

  df1 <- as.data.frame(df)

  b = apply(as.matrix(df1),2,as.character)

  #rename the column names of the matrix
  colnames(b) [1] = paste("x")

  mode(b) = "numeric"

  b2 <- as.data.frame(b)

  ch <- chull(b2)
  coords <- b2[c(ch, ch[1]), ]

  sp_poly <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(coords)), ID=1)))

  proj4string(sp_poly) <- CRS("+init=epsg:2100")

  sp_poly_df <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(sp_poly, data=data.frame(ID=1))

  test1 = spTransform(sp_poly_df, "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")

  writeOGR(obj=test1, dsn=paste0(mydir,save_name), layer = "r"
           driver="ESRI Shapefile", overwrite_layer = TRUE)

}

map2(temp$data,temp$savedir,~myfunction(.x,.y))
```

Comment: I think your answer has a mistake. When I run the code until the part before the `function` I am getting the following error: _Error in mutate(., data = map(value, ~read.table(., header = FALSE, sep = "",  : 
  is.data.frame(.data) || is.list(.data) || is.environment(.data) is not TRUE_. Also, if I change the `*.shp$` part with `.txt$` and I continue with the code at the end I am getting only 1 out of the 2 `shp` that I want to create.